# Is there a formal definition of what it means for a signal to be sparse?

Tags: signal-analysis, sparsity, sparse-model

Up to now I've never found a rigorous or a formal definition of what it means for a signal to be sparse other than it means that it has a relatively low number of non-zero entries or that the cardinality of its support is small. The only thing I've found close to a somewhat formal definition of a sparse signal is that a sparse signal is $K$-sparse in a transform basis $\Psi$ if there are exactly K nonzero elements. That definition is found in S. Brunton's book Data Driven Science & Engineering, p. 97.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.cosmostat.org/research-topics/sparsity-and-compressed-sensing) gives the following definition:

> A signal is said to be sparse
> if it can be represented in a basis or frame (e.g Fourier, Wavelets,
> Curvelets, etc.) in which the curve obtained by plotting the obtained
> coefficients, sorted by their decreasing absolute values, exhibits a
> polynomial decay.

Comment: This definition of sparseness is trivially true for all signals unless the basis is constrained in some way. So I'm not sure how useful it is.